# converted .htaccess to nginx is breaking my app

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, configuration

I have been working on this all day and still am not having no luck. I used an online .htaccess to config converter and so I don't think it converted everything correctly.

The following is my .htaccess file

```
    RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule     ^((.)?)$        index.php?p=home [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond     $1 !^(\#(.)*|\?(.)*|\.htaccess(.)*|\.htaccess\.back(.)*|.idea\/(.)*|.svn\/(.)*|admin\.php(.)*|content\/(.)*|download\.php(.)*|ecc\/(.)*|images\/(.)*|index\.php(.)*|install\/(.)*|login\.php(.)*|readme\.txt(.)*|robots\.txt(.)*)
    RewriteRule     ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

And my converted nginx config

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
location / {
   if ($query_string ~ "^$"){
    rewrite ^/((.)?)$ /index.php?p=home break;
  }
  if (-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1 break;
  }
  rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1&$query_string break;
}
location ~* (^(?!(?:(?!(php|inc)).)*/uploads/).*?(php)) {
                try_files $uri = 404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

What is happening is that when I try to go to a url like `/admin.php?p=settings&group=3`, it redirects me (because I believe it is not carrying the query string) to the login.
When I go to something like `/index.php?p=login` or `/index.php?p=signup` it works correctly.

Can someone help me on this.
-John

Comment: I changed `try_files$uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$uri&$args;` and I was able to see some urls but some are still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake that you're making is trying to translate the htaccess into an nginx conf.  The two config styles are quite different.  A better approach is to try to implement the *logic* of your htaccess in nginx.

So, you htaccess does the following:

1. When request contains no path (just the root of the domain), rewrite the request to /index.php?p=home
2. When request is a file, just return that
3. Third one's a little harder to grok.  You want to rewrite the request to index.php?url=&, except for some requests you want to protect, like '.svn'.

So, something like this perhaps (untested):

```
# Block some bad requests [3], only included a few here to get the idea
location ~ (\.svn|\.htaccess|\.last|robots\.txt) {
    deny all;
}
location / {
    # see if a file or dir corresponding to the request exists and use that [2]
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
# Rewrites [1] + [3]
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^$ /index.php?p=home break;
    rewrite $(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

As I say, untested, but this is more nginx-ish.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. I had a hard time switching the logic, this will help me see it better.

Comment: Ok this was very useful. It fixed my backend redirect problems but now I still have one other issue with the front end of the site. Front end urls are like wordpress permlinks. domain.com/hard-drives-hdd/samsung-spinpoint-400gb-hard-drive/ is just pulling up the home page now. Any ideas on what the change?